# Retrofit,onResponse method doesnt execute code in its body

Tags: android, listview, retrofit2, jsonresponse

Retrofit2, `onResponse` method doesn't execute code in its body. The app doesn't crash but the list is not showing up with data in the activity.
I created `log.e()` to see where my code was executing and not executing.the code in the on response didn't execute at all but the one in the `onFailure` did execute.

I see :

```
"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $ " in the logcat.
```

My interface

```
    public interface RadioApiClient {
        String BASE_URL = "https://api.broadcastify.com/audio/";
        String API_KEY = "1234567890";//dummy key
        String JSON_RESPONSE = "json";
        String XML_RESPONSE = "XML";

        //api.broadcastify.com/audio/?a=feeds&type=json&key=1234567890
        @GET(".")
        Call<List<Feeds>> getFeeds(@Query("a") String action,
                                   @Query("type") String reponseType,
                                   @Query("key") String key);

        @GET("api.broadcastify.com/audio/?a=feeds&type=json&key=1234567890")
        Call<List<Feeds>> getFeeds();

    }
```

My main activity

```
        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private ListView listView;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);


            final Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(RadioApiClient.BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
            Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

            RadioApiClient client = retrofit.create(RadioApiClient.class);

    //I checked if internet was connected

            if (isNetworkConnected()) {
                Log.e("success", "" + "Has internet");
            } else {
                Log.e("No success", "" + "no internet");

            }
            Call<List<Feeds>> call = client.getFeeds("feeds",
                    RadioApiClient.JSON_RESPONSE,
                    RadioApiClient.API_KEY);
            isNetworkConnected();
            Log.e("Accessing url", client.getFeeds("feeds",
                    RadioApiClient.JSON_RESPONSE,
                    RadioApiClient.API_KEY).request().url().toString());

   //all log.e excecuted apart from the one in the onResponse method

            call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Feeds>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<List<Feeds>> call, Response<List<Feeds>> response) {

                    Log.e("success", "" + "3");
                    List<Feeds> feeds = response.body();
                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    Log.e("success", "" + "4");
                    Log.e("Feedsize", "" + feeds.size());


                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, feeds.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Feeds>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, feeds));
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<List<Feeds>> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.e("no success", "" + "onfailure");
                    t.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        }

        private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null;
        }

    }
```

My Model

```
public class Radio {

    @SerializedName("Feeds")
    @Expose
    private List<Feeds> feeds = null;

    public List<Feeds> getFeeds() {
        return feeds;
    }

    public void setFeeds(List<Feeds> feeds) {
        this.feeds = feeds;
    }

}

      public class Feeds {

        @SerializedName("id")
        @Expose
        private int id;
        @SerializedName("status")
        @Expose
        private int status;
        @SerializedName("listeners")
        @Expose
        private int listeners;
        @SerializedName("descr")
        @Expose
        private String descr;
        @SerializedName("genre")
        @Expose
        private String genre;
        @SerializedName("mount")
        @Expose
        private String mount;
        @SerializedName("bitrate")
        @Expose
        private int bitrate;
        @SerializedName("Counties")
        @Expose
        private List<County> counties = null;
        @SerializedName("Relays")
        @Expose
        private List<Relay> relays = null;

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public int getStatus() {
            return status;
        }

        public void setStatus(int status) {
            this.status = status;
        }

        public int getListeners() {
            return listeners;
        }

        public void setListeners(int listeners) {
            this.listeners = listeners;
        }

        public String getDescr() {
            return descr;
        }

        public void setDescr(String descr) {
            this.descr = descr;
        }

        public String getGenre() {
            return genre;
        }

        public void setGenre(String genre) {
            this.genre = genre;
        }

        public String getMount() {
            return mount;
        }

        public void setMount(String mount) {
            this.mount = mount;
        }

        public int getBitrate() {
            return bitrate;
        }

        public void setBitrate(int bitrate) {
            this.bitrate = bitrate;
        }

        public List<County> getCounties() {
            return counties;
        }

        public void setCounties(List<County> counties) {
            this.counties = counties;
        }

        public List<Relay> getRelays() {
            return relays;
        }

        public void setRelays(List<Relay> relays) {
            this.relays = relays;
        }

    }
```

Comment: what is it printing in stacktrace?

Comment: You could try to add logging and see if the request is actually made/and if you get a response from the server: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-log-requests-and-responses

Comment: im getting:java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Answer (score 0):

Change Your code in RadioApiClient  to this

```
public interface RadioApiClient {

String BASE_URL = "https://api.broadcastify.com/";
String API_KEY = "1234567890";//dummy key
String JSON_RESPONSE = "json";
String XML_RESPONSE = "XML";

@GET("audio/?")
Call<List<Feeds>> getFeeds(
        @Query("a") String action,
        @Query("type") String responseType,
        @Query("key") String key);
```

}

Comment: it didnt work.its changed the url to a wrong one.its was changed to https://api.broadcastify.com/audio/audio/?&a=feeds&type=json&key=15670403 instead of https://api.broadcastify.com/audio/?&a=feeds&type=json&key=15670403

Answer (score 0):

i figured what was wrong.I had a radio class which had that has  a method which returned a list of feeds.i was using the radio feed object instead of the radio objeect which returned an array of feeds.that why the error :"Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT" was coming up